# php-sql code displays all data in the database instead of one

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i have this php form that search my database for a particular user using a tracking number that was assigned to each user ( each user different tracking) and the form is suppose to display the particular user that i am searching for but it end up displaying all the database

this is the php code

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "class";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT ctracking, cname, cemail, crport, cdport, clocation, cdestination FROM demo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "ctracking: " . $row["ctracking"]. " - Name: " . $row["cname"]. " - Email: " . $row["cemail"]. " - Port: " . $row["crport"]. " - Dport: " . $row["cdport"]." - Location: " . $row["clocation"]. " - Destination: " . $row["cdestination"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

this is the html form code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Static Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="making.php" method="post" />
 <h1>Britchi Tracking</h1>
    <p>
    Costumers Name (required) <br/>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Emmanuel John"' . '" size="70"/>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="csearch" value="Search"></p>
    </form>

<form action="http://localhost/wordpress">
<input type="submit" value="Go to Home Page">
</form
</body>

</html>
```

i want the code to display all the details of a particular user not all the database

Comment: where is your tracking number

Comment: my tracking number is saved on my database "phpmyadmin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to receive variable

```
$track_num=$_POST['search'];
```

And apply in your query .

```
$sql = "SELECT ctracking, cname, cemail, crport, cdport, clocation, cdestination FROM demo WHERE ctracking='$track_num'";
```

> NOTE:your code is open to sql injection attack use prepared statement.

Comment: please can you help me and add the ( $track_num=$_POST['search'];   ) on the line it is supposed to be @RahulShrivastava

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED HOW ABOUT MAKING IT SAVE FROM SQL INJECTION AS YOU ADVISED @RahulShrivastava

Comment: Use pdo instead of mysqli

Comment: Search about pdo lot of tutorial available

Comment: for me to use the pdo do  i need to change the whole code?

Comment: If you want more security use pdo

Comment: Otherwise read about mysqli security you can improve the security with mysqli too

Comment: please give me your social media account so i can chat with you, i only have 5 reputation and it is not enough to go into the discussion section please

Comment: Currently this is not possible because i am out of office you can comment tomorrow i will create chat for you